# NodeRed Function Node Crashes - [red] Uncaught Exception:

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I am having a hard time understanding why my Node-Red Flow keeps crashing with an [RED] Uncaught Exception. It almost seems like the function node is crashing and my code inside of the function node never has a chance to catch it.

I have a very simple Node-Red flow that executes a IBMDB node.js library to insert data into my database. In order to use the IBMDB library, I had to add the package to the list of packages in my packages.json file. I also had to setup a global context variable inside the Bluemix-setings.js file. I named this global context variable IBMDB, which is the equivalent to the require statement. Once that was done, I am able to make use of the library inside a function node.

** Here is the Node.js IBMDB library, I am using. 
https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db

** Here is the Flow
[image: Node-Red Flow]

** Here is the code inside the function.

```
try {
context.global.ibmdb.open("DATABASE=database;HOSTNAME=hostname;PORT=port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=username;PWD=password;", function (err,conn) {

  conn.beginTransaction(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      //could not begin a transaction for some reason.
      console.log(err);
      return conn.closeSync();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < msg.payload.Readings.length; i++) 
    { 
        var result = conn.querySync("INSERT INTO db2.table (" + 
                                    "I_ID," +
                                    "D_ID," +
                                    "field1," +
                                    "field2," +
                                    "field3," +
                                    "field4," +
                                    "field5," +
                                    "field6," +
                                    "field7," +
                                    "field8," +
                                    "field9," +
                                    "field10)" +
                                    "values (" +
                                    "1A," +
                                    "'"+ msg.payload.field1 + "',"+
                                    "'" + JSON.stringify(msg.payload.Readings[i].field2) + "'," +
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field3 + ","+
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field4 + ","+
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field5 + ","+
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field6 + ","+
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field7 + ","+
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field8 + ","+
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field9 + ","+
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field10 + ","+
                                    "'2016-05-31 22:28:51.000000'" +
                                    ");");
    }

    conn.commitTransaction(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        //error during commit
        console.log("****ERROR: " + err);
        node.error("**** ERROR: ", err);
        //return conn.closeSync();
      }

      //Close the connection
      conn.closeSync();
    });
  });
});
} catch (e) {
    node.error("**** ERROR: ", err); 
}
```

When I run this with a valid SQL statement and all the data types are correctly sent, I get no errors. Everything works!!

*** The issue:  When I did some testing to force a SQL error, the Node-Red instance crashes. I forced the error by sending a valid SQL statement, but the data elements in one of the fields is a non-numeric value where the table definition is expecting numeric only. I see in the error logs (console out) two lines..

- The error SQL error message displayed is exactly what I was expecting to catch in my application. Instead the application just crashes.

> [red] Uncaught Exception: Error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664]
>   SQL0103N  The numeric literal "1A" is not valid.  SQLSTATE=42604

Any insight on what is really happening would be greatly appreciated. I am wondering if I put this code inside a custom built node would I be able to catch the error. Could this be a limitation of using the function node as a wrapper to my code. ????
*

Comment: Try wrapping the `conn.querySync` call in it's own try/catch block. The current block is out of scope because the call happens in another function (the one passed into `beginTransaction`). Also any reason you're rolling your own rather than the existing node https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-db2?

Comment: THANK YOU.. !!!!  That worked!!! - I did some experimenting with the contrib-db2 node, but since my data comes into the node as an array of elements that needs to be individually inserted into the database, I was struggling with how I could run multiple SQL inserts in a for loop. I guess I could have done a loop in the flow, but I started down this path thinking it would be easier. Looking back, I probably made a bad decision. Again.. THANK YOU.. You saved the day!!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the conn.querySync call in it's own try/catch block. The current block is out of scope because the call happens in another function (the one passed into beginTransaction).

e.g.

```
try {
context.global.ibmdb.open("DATABASE=database;HOSTNAME=hostname;PORT=port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=username;PWD=password;", function (err,conn) {

  conn.beginTransaction(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      //could not begin a transaction for some reason.
      console.log(err);
      return conn.closeSync();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < msg.payload.Readings.length; i++) 
    {
      try {
        var result = conn.querySync("INSERT INTO db2.table (" + 
                                    "I_ID," +
                                    "D_ID," +
                                    "field1," +
                                    "field2," +
                                    "field3," +
                                    "field4," +
                                    "field5," +
                                    "field6," +
                                    "field7," +
                                    "field8," +
                                    "field9," +
                                    "field10)" +
                                    "values (" +
                                    "1A," +
                                    "'"+ msg.payload.field1 + "',"+
                                    "'" + JSON.stringify(msg.payload.Readings[i].field2) + "'," +
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field3 + ","+
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field4 + ","+
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field5 + ","+
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field6 + ","+
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field7 + ","+
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field8 + ","+
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field9 + ","+
                                    msg.payload.Readings[i].field10 + ","+
                                    "'2016-05-31 22:28:51.000000'" +
                                    ");");
      } catch (excp) {
         //do stuff
      }
    }

    conn.commitTransaction(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        //error during commit
        console.log("****ERROR: " + err);
        node.error("**** ERROR: ", err);
        //return conn.closeSync();
      }

      //Close the connection
      conn.closeSync();
    });
  });
});
} catch (e) {
    node.error("**** ERROR: ", e); 
}
```